# Excel VBA 'Selection.Filldown' copying cell above selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a Macro that deals with a a set of filtered rows. The user needs to be able to create any number of rows for this macro to apply to, and there are some hidden rows due to the filter so I don't believe I can tell excel to select the next 100 rows to apply the macro to, as that would apply to the hidden cells.

The first part of the Macro goes like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AW$377").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AW$377").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("AB2").Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-11]=""Monday"",RC[-12],""DELETE"")"
Range("AB2").Select
Selection.FillDown
```

That filldown command works perfectly whe I record the macro, but when it runs, instead of copying that cell down into all applicable cells below, it copys the header cell above it into the destination cell.

Is there another command I can use to get this running properly?

Comment: With FillDown you would need to select the full range into which the formula should be filled. ie `Range("AB2:AB377").FillDown` then it would use the top cell as the model.  If only one cell/row is passed in, it will use the cell above it as the model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if it is possible to have it only fill down into the filtered cells? I am worried that if I apply that range, the hidden filtered cells will get values that they should not.

Comment: `Range("AB2:AB377").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-11]=""Monday"",RC[-12],""DELETE"")"`

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much Scott!